# List of free Finder shortcuts?

Tags: macos, keyboard, finder, shortcut

I use many services/quick actions and am running out of good shortcuts. The Internet is flooded with Finder shortcut articles, but is there any chance someone will point me to a list of available, non-conflicting combinations? (Or maybe, even better, disable useless default commands?)

Comment: Thank you for your downvote without commenting. Very helpful.

Comment: If you have used Google, then you will find many sites that do list Finder shortcuts. And, BTW, I have never found one yet that has to be paid for...

Comment: @SolarMike - free as in *available* not free as in *beer* or *speech*.

Comment: How many do you need? You've got 48 off the bat with alphanumeric + F-keys, per modifier combination. As far as I'm aware, nothing uses all 4, so there's your first 'free' 48. I'm almost certain nothing in Finder uses 3 out of 4, so that's 96...

Comment: ah, sort by uses 3 + numbers, so you're down to maybe 86. [BTW, I sympathise. I used to live in an app that had so many commandable functions you really couldn't set keys for them all. I eventually gave up trying, mainly because I couldn't remember them all, long before i ran out of available keys.]

Comment: There are a few apps that show you what shortcuts are USED by the current application, but I don't think I've seen one that will show you which are vacant.

Comment: @benwiggy - probably because there are, if my [failed] schoolboy math is anywhere close, something like 450 possible combinations without even touching non-alphanumeric, or even differentiating between the numbers above qwerty vs the numpad [which the Mac does differentiate].

Comment: Have a look at: https://www.mediaatelier.com/CheatSheet/?ref=CustomShortcuts

Comment: @user3439894 That's it! I couldn't remember the name and was just searching hopelessly.

Comment: @solarMike lol, I want exactly the opposite, a list of NO shortcuts.

Comment: @Tetsujin yeah, of course you can always find weird combinations, but I want those cool nice handy one hand easy to remember shortcuts.

Comment: We all do - unfortunately they're the ones apps use up first. You won't find anything better than cheat sheet [which I didn't mention earlier because it doesn't do what you want - but no-one's ever going to make an app with the other 400 spare shortcuts in a list.

Comment: @MateusRibeiro full marks for speed... Sorry someone else got there before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use an *application* name [**CheatSheet**](https://www.mediaatelier.com/CheatSheet/?ref=CustomShortcuts) to ascertain existing *keyboard shortcuts* for any given *application*.

On my system for **Finder**, it shows the following as specific existing *keyboard shortcuts* for its menus, and from that I can pick a *keyboard shortcut* that isn't already assigned in order to give to a *Service/Quick Action*:

<sup>I have many custom assigned *keyboard shortcuts* for *Services/Quick Actions* using three and four modifier keys in addition to another *character* on the *keyboard*.</sup>

**Finder**

| Shortcut | Command |
| --- | --- |
| ⌘, | Preferences... |
| ⌥⌘N | Make New Folder |
| ⌘↩ | New Terminal Window |
| ⌥⌘/ | Swap Split View Windows |
| ⌘H | Hide Finder |
| ⌥⌘H | Hide Others |
| ⌘Q | Quit Finder |
| ⌥⌘Q | Quit and Keep Windows |

**File**

| Shortcut | Command |
| --- | --- |
| ⌘N | New Finder Window |
| ⇧⌘ N | New Folder |
| ⌘T | New Tab |
| ⌃⌘O | Open in New Tab |
| ⌥⌘W | Close All |
| ⌘I | GetInfo |
| ⌥⌘I | Show Inspector |
| ⌃⌘I | Get Summary Info |
| ⌘F | Find |
| ⌃⇧⌘F | Find by Name… |
| ⌥⌘F | Set Focus To Search Field |

**Edit**

| Shortcut | Command |
| --- | --- |
| ⌘Z | Undo |
| ⌥⌘C | Copy “...” as Pathname |
| ⌘A | Select All |
| ⌘R | Rotate Right |
| ⌥⌘R | Rotate Left |
| ⌘L | Rotate Left |
| fn fn | Start Dictation… |
| ⌃⌘␣ | Emoji & Symbols |

**View**

| Shortcut | Command |
| --- | --- |
| ⌃⌘0 | Use Stacks |
| ⌃⌥⌘0 | None |
| ⌃⌥⌘1 | Name |
| ⌃⌥⌘2 | Kind |
| ⌃⌥⌘3 | Date Last Opened |
| ⌃⌥⌘4 | Date Added |
| ⌃⌥⌘5 | Date Modified |
| ⌃⌥⌘6 | Size |
| ⌃⌥⌘7 | Tags |
| ⌘J | Show View Options |
| ⌘+ | Increase Icon Size |
| ⌘- | Decrease Icon Size |

**Go**

| Shortcut | Command |
| --- | --- |
| ⌘↑ | Enclosing Folder |
| ⌥⌘↑ | Enclosing Folder |
| ⌃⌘ | ↑ Enclosing Folder in New Window |
| ⇧⌘↑ | Select Startup Disk on Desktop |
| ⌥⌘↓ | Open Selection |
| ⇧⌘F | Recents |
| ⇧⌘O | Documents |
| ⇧⌘D | Desktop |
| ⌥⌘L | Downloads |
| ⇧⌘H | Home |
| ⇧⌘C | Computer |
| ⇧⌘R | AirDrop |
| ⇧⌘K | Network |
| ⇧⌘I | iCloud Drive |
| ⇧⌘A | Applications |
| ⇧⌘U | Utilities |
| ⇧⌘G | Go to Folder… |
| ⌘K | ConnecttoServer… |

**Window**

| Shortcut | Command |
| --- | --- |
| ⌥⌘M | Minimize All |
| ⌘` | Cycle Through Windows |

**Notes:**

Unfortunately CheatSheet misses some assigned *keyboard shortcuts*, so visual verification may be needed before assigning a custom *keyboard shortcut*.

Comment: Thanks! Do you get paid to do all this work?