# How to disable "Rotate Right" Finder shortcut?

Tags: keyboard, finder

I've just found out that the Finder has the ability to make changes to the contents of image and video files using these shortcuts:

- ⌘R - Rotate Right
- ⌘L - Rotate Left
- ⌥⌘R - Rotate Left

(Thanks to this [list](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/425025/list-of-free-finder-shortcuts#425028).)

These actions don't show up in the Finder's menus. The only time I see "Rotate Right" or "Rotate Left" in the menus is *after* the action. The text for the undo action becomes "Undo Rotate Right" (or Left).

Anyway, the last thing I want to do is change to the contents of files in Finder by accidentally pressing these keys. I've tried this [trick](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/223190/mac-change-finder-shortcuts#223221) to disable these actions, assigning  "Rotate Right" and "Rotate Left" to some hard to press combinations.

But only "Rotate Left" becomes disabled. `⌘R` stubbornly keeps working.

I've even checked with [CheatSheet](https://www.mediaatelier.com/CheatSheet) that my shortcuts are indeed in place.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to bind ⌘R to something valid. While I haven't figured out where this behaviour is originating from (⌘R does not flash any menubar item but it does if you bind "Rotate Right" which is seemingly a hidden menu bar entry?) I found a workaround.

This workaround **disables** ⌘R in Finder. If you want ⌘R to do *something* you can just rebind it to that. If you bind it to something non-existing however it will still rotate. That is the workaround, providing a noop menu entry (doing nothing).

1. Start "Automator"
2. Create new document and select "Quick Action". A window opens with a list on the left and a workflow area on the right.
3. Change the first line in the workflow area so that "Workflow receives current" is set to "files or folders" and - if you want this service only to show up in Finder - set "in" to "Finder.app"
4. Save it (⌘S) and give it a name such as "Disable Action" (doesn't really matter but you need it for...)
5. Assign ⌘R to "Disable Action" in keyboard shortcut preferences

You can still:

- Press space (quicklook) and use ⌘R to rotate there
- Bind "Rotate Right" to another key if you want to retain that functionality in Finder

[image: automator example]

Comment: Works alright, thanks